# How to make case-insensitive serach to Cyrillic letters django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tryid to create search in django and make it case-insensitive. I created it, but it doesn't work with cyrillic (russian) letters.

```
# views.py
class QuestionsAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    search_fields = ['name_tm', 'name_ru', 'name_en']
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionsAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

With latin letter it works:
[image]

But with russian letter not works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using database-wise? Ensure that you have utf8 as the default encoding on the database end

Comment: no, i getting posted data with string.title(). I changed my db to postgres, but it didnt help me